# Import CSV, row by row, into custom table

Tags: 8, forms, importing-exporting

I have a Drupal 7 submit method for updating CSV row by row to a custom table which I found under this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968406/drupal-7-import-csv-row-by-row-into-custom-table). I have tried to update it so that it works in Drupal 8 to no avail. How do I to modify it to work in Drupal 8?

```
function custom_module_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $file = $form_state['values']['csv_upload_file'];
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    $file->filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $file->filename);
    file_save($file);

    $csv_file = file_load($file->fid);
    $file = fopen($csv_file->uri, "r");


    while(! feof($file))
    {
        $customer = fgetcsv($file));
        db_insert('your_db_table')
            ->fields(array(
                'column1' => $customer[0],
                'column2' => $customer[1]
            ))
            ->execute();
    }

    fclose($file);

    drupal_set_message('CSV data added to the database');
}
```

The Drupal 8 code that I am trying to use is as below:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $file = $form_state->getValue('csv_upload');
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    $file->filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $file->filename);
    file_save_data($file);

    $csv_file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file->fid);
    $file = fopen($csv_file->getFileUri(), "r");

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $customer = fgetcsv($file);
        \Drupal::database()->insert('your_db_table')
            ->fields(array(
                'column1' => $customer[0],
                'column2' => $customer[1]
            ))
            ->execute();
    }

    fclose($file);

    drupal_set_message('CSV data added to the database');
}
```

Errors include:

1. Fatal error: Call to a member function getFileUri() on null in /home/annuities/public_html/modules/custom_module/src/Form/C‌​ustomForm.php on line 90.

Line 90: `$file = fopen($csv_file->getFileUri(), "r");`

2. Warning: Creating default object from empty value in Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm->submitForm() (line 85 of modules/custom_module/src/Form/CustomForm.php).

Line 85: `$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;`

3. Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filename in Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm->submitForm() (line 86 of modules/custom_module/src/Form/CustomForm.php).

Line 86: `$file->filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $file->filename);`

4. The file could not be created.
   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$fid in Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm->submitForm() (line 89 of modules/custom_module/src/Form/CustomForm.php).

Line 89: `$csv_file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file->fid);`

5. Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple() (line 227 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).

Comment: What did you try?  The code you posted in this question is exactly the same code in the SO post.

Comment: Hello Patrick. I have edited the question to show the drupal 8 code I am using. Thanks.

Comment: And what error are you getting?  What do the logs show?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getFileUri() on null in /home/annuities/public_html/modules/custom_module/src/Form/CustomForm.php on line 90. Line 90 corresponds to $file = fopen($csv_file->getFileUri(), "r");

Comment: When you debug with something like `kint($csv_file);` what do you see?  That error suggests that `$csv_file` is empty.

Comment: kint($csv_file); doesnt show anything.

Comment: Does `$form_state['values']['csv_upload_file'];` have a value?  *Drupal Answers* is not a code-writing service; you have to debug the code yourself and when you get stuck, post the specific error and specific code at hand.

Answer (score 2):

I used the code below;

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{

    $file = $form_state->getValue('csv_upload_file');

    $destination = $file[0]->toArray()['uri'][0]['value'];

    $file = fopen($destination, "r");

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $customer = fgetcsv($file);
        \Drupal::database()->insert('your_db_table')
            ->fields(array(
                'column1' => $customer[0],
                'column2' => $customer[1]
            ))
            ->execute();
    }

    fclose($file);

    drupal_set_message('CSV data added to the database');
}
```

Comment: Did this work? If it works, I'll use it too.

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://www.digitalnadeem.com/2020/02/01/how-to-import-excel-data-to-drupal-with-custom-module/) article.it says how you can have full control over each excel cell value and insert data into a custom table.

Comment: While linking to articles is fine they can die. You should pull the relevant parts of the code/text from your the referenced page and explain how it can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$file = $form_state->getValue('csv_upload_file');

It will return just file ids. You need to load file I think.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).